# Random character in RegEx replace

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

I want to replace **G$0** in the string **gantt(G$0,$A4,$B4)** with **gantt(<>G$0<>,$A4,$B4)**. So I have the following code:

```
var str = '=gantt(G$0,$A4,$B4) ';
var val = "G$0";
var val2 = val.replace(/\$/, "\\$")
var reg = new RegExp(val2, 'g');
var str = str.replace(reg, '<>' + val + '<>');
```

The result *in IE* is: **=gantt(<>GG$0<>,$A4,$B4)**  (*note the GG*). The problem seems to be IE10 specific.

Why is this happening, is this an **IE bug**?

**The replace should assume a string could contain multiple instances of **G$0****.

Comment: You didn't escape `$` from the string...

Comment: I see, I tried, seems to work here http://jsbin.com/notuqi/1/edit

Comment: Try your example in IE - looks like it may be an IE bug.

Comment: I can reproduce in IE10, but neither FF or Chrome. After testing in these environments, make sure to update the question with such information.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use RegEx at all. Stick to regular string replacement, and you won't have to escape the val string.

```
var str = '=gantt(G$0,$A4,$B4) ';
var val = "G$0";
var result = str.replace(val, '<>' + val + '<>');
```

If you want to replace multiple instances of `val` this can be done with `.split` and `.join`:

```
var str = '=gantt(G$0,$A4,$B4,G$0) ';
var val = "G$0";
var result = str.split(val).join('<>' + val + '<>');
```

Comment: I prefer not to use this, as it assumes only one instance of G$0.